# Trigger doesn't fire when row is inserted

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I built a trigger in SQL Server to execute a stored procedure when a new row is inserted into the table `Balance Data`, but the trigger doesn't get fired. I don't know what I am doing wrong or what is happening.

This is the script:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[SP_Trigger] 
ON [dbo].[BalanceData] 
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Exec Schenck.dbo.spCopyData
END
```

Comment: I would start by removing the Exec statement from the trigger and doing something less problematic. Create a dummy table and insert a row into it from the trigger. I suspect the trigger is firing and your problem in in the stored proc.

Comment: Is that trigger accessing a stored proc in another database (I note you're using a three-part name)? I'd usually recommend again accessing anything external to the trigger's own database. You can use e.g. service broker or even just a plain table to queue up work to happen elsewhere, which allows you to avoid coupling the databases together.

Comment: So instead of the Stored Proc i should have something like this ?

Comment: TRIGGER [dbo].[SP_Trigger] 
   ON  [dbo].[BalanceData] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 Select Top (1) *  from dbo.BalanceData 
 Order by [Time] desc 

 Insert Into Schenck.dbo.GetActualData
 Values (Values to insert)

END

Comment: Also, if this is SQL Server (please [edit] and at least add an extra tag for your database system. Triggers are far from standard), the most common mistake with triggers is to assume they fire once per row, when in fact they fire once per statement.

Comment: Yes this is for SQL, but i don't understand what you refer, with -- (please edit and at least add an extra tag for your database system. Triggers are far from standard)--
Can you explain me that point?

Comment: He mean you should include a tag in your question with your rdbms name `sql server`, `mySql`, `Postgres`, etc..

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using Transact-SQL.

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189799.aspx), `FOR INSERT` triggers are synonymous with `AFTER INSERT` triggers by default. This should fire after you have inserted your data into `[dbo].[BalanceData]`.

I would firstly confirm that the data has been inserted successfully (i.e. no check constraint violations, etc) and then confirm what `Schenck.dbo.spCopyData` is doing. You have turned `ROWCOUNT` off in the trigger, so perhaps this has given you the *illusion* that nothing happened.

Comment: I already check the performance of the SPCopyData and it run just fine, but once in the trigger, it never fire.

Comment: Another thing I thought of is that triggers can be disabled individually or within the database. Could you confirm that the triggers are enabled?: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189748.aspx

Comment: Yes the trigger appears enable.  i check the syntax and all looks correct, but still not fired

Comment: Darn. This exhausts my ideas. Sorry. :\